# How order by clause works in mysql, ordering shows wierd behaviour

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have a simple query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name order by non_unique_column LIMIT 0,50
```

This gives me list of records in some order.

But when I am removing `*` and putting `some column names` from the table, then it is changing the list order.

For `some` combination of columns in select clause it is giving different order.

I am not able to find, what pattern of column names in select clause gives different ordering.

So I am asking does any one had this kind of problem? or can any one suggest how the order by clause works in this scenario?

**Note:** If I am adding all the columns in select clause it gives me same result as *.

Please feel free to suggest any possible suggestion.

Thanks.

**Update:** Also when I am changing limit clause like `LIMIT 0,50` to `LIMIT 0,15`, I am getting different sets of records.

**Update2:**

I have created a sqlfiddle :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f2340/3

Please see the result from below queries

```
SELECT `M_ID`, `CON_FRST_NM`, `CON_PREFIX`, `CON_LST_NM`, `CON_MOB`,`CON_FAX` FROM `sample_table` order by `CON_PREFIX` LIMIT 0,60 

SELECT `M_ID`, `CON_FRST_NM`, `CON_PREFIX`, `CON_LST_NM`, `CON_MOB` FROM `sample_table` order by `CON_PREFIX` LIMIT 0,60
```

The only difference in the query is `CON_FAX` is not present in select clause of second query.

Please help me out why this difference is coming.

And also please see the result of below queries with different limit clause.
Note: It is second query from above queries.

```
SELECT `M_ID`, `CON_FRST_NM`, `CON_PREFIX`, `CON_LST_NM`, `CON_MOB` FROM `sample_table` order by `CON_PREFIX` LIMIT 0,60 

SELECT `M_ID`, `CON_FRST_NM`, `CON_PREFIX`, `CON_LST_NM`, `CON_MOB` FROM `sample_table` order by `CON_PREFIX` LIMIT 0,15
```

Thanks.

**PERSONAL OPINION:** *I see this as a bug/defect, because even if I haven't defined any unique order by clause and mysql is applying some random ordering based on its calculations, I feel it should not depend on what is present in select clause. My problem is for a given set of records it should return same ordered records regardless of whatever column I am selecting.*

Comment: Shouldnt really be happening, can we see some example data?

Comment: I am sure that can't be.

Comment: that is not how order by works, so theres nothing we can do for you till you post some data, a sqlfiddle would be preferable

Comment: I understand your point, I also thought this is not possible, but it is happening. Let me try to put some table data in my question.

Comment: Also when I am changing limit clause like LIMIT 0,50 to LIMIT 0,15, I am getting different sets of records.

Comment: That `also` doesn't help. Only example data and code which can reproduce this problem can help :)

Comment: Give me some time. I will try to make some sample data and try out on that if same thing happens in that also. And provide you the example. :)

Comment: Simple rule - if you want consistent ordering, you *have* to use an `ORDER BY` clause that unambiguously determines the order for *every* row. Anything else is just implementation details and may be subject to change at any time.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, I have updated my question, please see the results of different queries.

Comment: Have you read my comment? Your example doesn't make a difference. The **only** way to **guarantee** ordering is to use enough columns/expressions in your `ORDER BY` such that each row can be uniquely ordered.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, can you also please look at limit related queries.

Comment: The only column in all of your `ORDER BY` clauses is `CON_PREFIX`. Is that column sufficient to uniquely determine the order of all rows? No. Therefore there's *no* guarantee on what order rows will be delivered in. The fact that your *observing* different orderings is just further demonstration that there's no guarantee. And the only way to obtain a guaranteed order is to add more columns to the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @NamanGala the limit has nothing to do with this. you are saying give me rows with mr first then mrs second. since that is the only thing you put in the order by theres no way for mysql to know which mr's to show first and which mrs's to show second. so there is no guarantee (like my answer says) for the exact same ordering... it is doing exactly what it is supposed to... gives you mr. first and mrs. second

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Please have look at my updated question `PERSONAL OPINION`.

Comment: Put it this way - depending on the other parts of the query, it may be more efficient for the database to obtain the results using technique A (maybe using one particular index) or technique B (maybe accumulating results and using some form of hash table) - those techniques may produce results in different orders. The server *then* uses the only information you've given it about the sort order that you *want* and does the minimum required to produce that result. Anything else would be wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with this is because there is a duplicated value that you specify for your order by aka its either Mr. or Mrs. there is no guaranteed select order with this because they are all Mr. or Mrs.

if you want to ensure that it is always going to be in a specific order then you should also include the primary key as a second ordering to keep it all the same.. aka

```
ORDER BY CON_PREFIX ASC, M_ID ASC
```

as it stands right now `ORDER BY CON_PREFIX` is giving you exactly what it should be giving you, the prefixes in ascending order, there is nothing related to the limit for causing this, you simply just havent told MySQL how else you want the data to be returned to you.

---

to respond to your `PERSONAL OPINION` edit in the question....
what you are describing is unreasonable, think of it this way any default order that would be used to pull out data is now gone because you are specifying an order by. if there wasn't any order by on the clause then mysql has a generic select pattern but again that is gone once you put an order by on the query

Comment: Thanks for answering, can you also please look at limit related queries

Comment: i did. do you not understand what I said in my answer?

Comment: I understand what point you are making. As I have defined CON_PREFIX as my ordering which is non_unique, so my_sql is giving some random order which is `Acceptable behaviour`. Now if I change my select clause from selecting only single column or all the column, it should give me that ordered records regardless of my select clause.

Comment: @NamanGala you cant guarantee it will be the same with the same columns... if you run the select multiple times it may be different or mysql may use the same select in memory to return results, but the fact of the matter is you cannot ensure it will be the same if you run any of those queries 10 times in a row

Comment: Let me try a single query 10 times and check if the results are changing.

Comment: @NamanGala i think it will probably be the same because mysql will optimize and store the results of an identical query in memory. try running it and then restart your computer and do it again or wait till tomorrow and try again

Answer (score -1):

The order by clause works from left to right
Let me give an example

If you use 
SELECT serialNo,Name FROM table_name order by serialNo,Name;

what this does it it will order serialNo in the first instance and then it will order Name in the second instance . When it orders name in the second instance the oredering of the serialNo will change according to the ordering of the name .

Hope I was clear in my explanation .

Comment: not true, if you specify a specific column to order by then there wouldn't be an additional ordering that would cause the original one to be skewed

Comment: Please shed some light for voting down my answer .

Comment: @JohnRuddell then how do you think my query would work ? On what basis will the ordering happen for my query ?

Comment: well depends on the column you specify in the order by.. the OP said non_unique_column, lets just say that is `Name` in your query, then ORDER BY `Name` will return all rows where the name is in alphabetical order in ascending fashion since that is the default

Comment: now with your edit I can see you really missed the point of the question. the question was an ORDER BY on only one column not more than one.

Comment: So if my understanding is right , you are telling that the ordering will happen only on the serialNo and not on the name?

Comment: @Justin look at the op's query... his query is equivalent to yours like this... `SELECT serialNo,Name,age FROM table_name order by serialNo LIMIT 0,50` there is no other column specified in the order by.

Comment: @JohnRuddell OOPS my mistake .  :( Jumped into conclusion without reading it properly .

Comment: @Justin no problem, I was trying to make it clear, sorry for not explaining it better sooner

Comment: @Justin you can also delete your answer to get your reputation points back if you would like :)