# Mysql Order by clause for decending order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

In reference to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28061227/3898076).

I appended M_id in my order by clause to make it unique ordering.

I have created a sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f2340/3

Now I am facing issue with `DESC` ordering.

Below queries giving expected results.

```
SELECT `M_ID`, `CON_FRST_NM` FROM `sample_table` order by `CON_FRST_NM` LIMIT 0,60

SELECT `M_ID`, `CON_FRST_NM` FROM `sample_table` order by `CON_FRST_NM`,`M_ID` LIMIT 0,60

SELECT `M_ID`, `CON_FRST_NM` FROM `sample_table` order by `CON_FRST_NM`,`M_ID` ASC LIMIT 0,60

SELECT `M_ID`, `CON_FRST_NM` FROM `sample_table` order by `CON_FRST_NM` DESC LIMIT 0,60
```

Below query is not giving expected result.

```
SELECT `M_ID`, `CON_FRST_NM` FROM `sample_table` order by `CON_FRST_NM`,`M_ID` DESC LIMIT 0,60
```

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: And what is your expected result ?

Comment: Ordering coming in ascending order.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f2340/22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want the `desc` on the first key in the `order by`:

```
SELECT `M_ID`, `CON_FRST_NM`
FROM `sample_table`
ORDER BY `CON_FRST_NM` DESC, `M_ID`
LIMIT 0, 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort different columns in diffrent directions. For example-

```
SELECT `M_ID`, `CON_FRST_NM`
FROM `sample_table`
ORDER BY `CON_FRST_NM` DESC, `M_ID` ASC
LIMIT 0, 60;
```

or

```
SELECT `M_ID`, `CON_FRST_NM`
FROM `sample_table`
ORDER BY `CON_FRST_NM` DESC, `M_ID` DESC
LIMIT 0, 60;
```

if you do not mention the direction, ASC is default. So, in your query which is

```
SELECT `M_ID`, `CON_FRST_NM`
FROM `sample_table`
ORDER BY `CON_FRST_NM`, `M_ID` DESC
LIMIT 0, 60;
```

Results will be first sorted by `CON_FRST_NM` in ascending order and then by `M_ID` in descending order.